# Why does my framing nailer ocasionally leak from around the trigger?

Tags: tools, powertools

I have a Hitachi NR90AC5 framing nailer that still functions correctly, but some air leaks from around the trigger. Sometimes, after firing a few nails, it doesn't leak air anymore. Then later after more nails are fired, it goes back to leaking again. The performance of the gun is unaffected, but I'm concerned something may be wearing out.

It hasn't been used that heavily and I oil it every day.

What part needs replaced to make it stop occasionally leaking from the trigger?

Comment: https://www.ereplacementparts.com/repair-center/article/2041/How_to_Diagnose_Power_Air_Nailers.html?osCsid=msckuds5mt110fr8f9mmval1t5.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned.

Comment: It's not abandoned. No one has answered it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I have repaired all the internal parts for the trigger assembly multiple times. Works for a while then begins to leak again. Adding grease to the o rings helps but it’s just a junk trigger assembly.

Comment: Paslode are awesome and don't have this problem.  But they cost an arm and a leg